# Wireless Card Dumping Lots of Log Messages (13GiB+ over a few hours)

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, logging

My USB wifi adapter (TL-WN822N running on Fedora 20 with the ath9k_htc adapter) seems to be working fine but is dumping similar debugging messages multiple times per second. The messages are so large and so frequent that I ended up having a /var/log/messages file of > 13GiB, only stopping because my root partition ran out of space.

---

UPDATE 2014-06-28 9:20PM:

I shuffled some devices around and apparently this only happens when the adapter is connected through my USB hub.

---

The messages look like this:

```
Jun 28 17:39:23 localhost kernel: ------------[ cut here ]------------
Jun 28 17:39:23 localhost kernel: WARNING: CPU: 1 PID: 1312 at drivers/usb/core/urb.c:450 usb_submit_urb+0x1fd/0x5c0()
Jun 28 17:39:23 localhost kernel: usb 3-1.3: BOGUS urb xfer, pipe 1 != type 3
Jun 28 17:39:23 localhost kernel: Modules linked in: tun fuse rfcomm nf_conntrack_netbios_ns nf_conntrack_broadcast ccm ip6t_rpfilter ip6t_REJECT xt_conntrack bnep ath9k_htc ath9k_common ath9k_hw ath ebtable_nat ebtable_broute bridge stp llc ebtable_filter ebtables ip6table_nat nf_conntrack_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_nat_ipv6 ip6table_mangle ip6table_security ip6table_raw ip6table_filter ip6_tables iptable_nat nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 nf_nat_ipv4 nf_nat nf_conntrack iptable_mangle iptable_security iptable_raw amd_iommu_v2 btusb bluetooth arc4 radeon rtl8723ae rtl_pci rtlwifi mac80211 x86_pkg_temp_thermal iTCO_wdt coretemp kvm_intel iTCO_vendor_support uvcvideo i2c_algo_bit kvm ttm videobuf2_vmalloc toshiba_acpi snd_seq cfg80211 snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic videobuf2_memops drm_kms_helper
Jun 28 17:39:23 localhost kernel: 6lowpan_iphc videobuf2_core snd_hda_intel drm snd_hda_codec snd_hwdep snd_seq_device sparse_keymap videodev shpchp media snd_pcm mei_me mei rfkill i2c_i801 microcode joydev lpc_ich snd_timer snd mfd_core i2c_core serio_raw soundcore wmi toshiba_bluetooth video nfsd auth_rpcgss nfs_acl lockd binfmt_misc sunrpc dm_crypt crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul crc32c_intel ghash_clmulni_intel alx usb_storage mdio vboxnetadp(OF) vboxnetflt(OF) vboxdrv(OF)
Jun 28 17:39:23 localhost kernel: CPU: 1 PID: 1312 Comm: NetworkManager Tainted: GF       W  O 3.14.8-200.fc20.x86_64 #1
Jun 28 17:39:23 localhost kernel: Hardware name: TOSHIBA Satellite S855/Portable PC, BIOS 1.60 04/20/2012
Jun 28 17:39:23 localhost kernel: 0000000000000000 0000000090064001 ffff8800a9339370 ffffffff816f0502
Jun 28 17:39:23 localhost kernel: ffff8800a93393b8 ffff8800a93393a8 ffffffff8108a1cd ffff88024170fcc0
Jun 28 17:39:23 localhost kernel: ffff8800a9258000 0000000000000002 0000000000000001 00000000000000d0
Jun 28 17:39:23 localhost kernel: Call Trace:
Jun 28 17:39:23 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff816f0502>] dump_stack+0x45/0x56
Jun 28 17:39:23 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff8108a1cd>] warn_slowpath_common+0x7d/0xa0
Jun 28 17:39:23 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff8108a24c>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x5c/0x80
Jun 28 17:39:23 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff8109722a>] ? del_timer_sync+0x4a/0x60
Jun 28 17:39:23 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff814e4d0d>] usb_submit_urb+0x1fd/0x5c0
Jun 28 17:39:23 localhost kernel: [<ffffffffa0895a89>] hif_usb_send+0xe9/0x360 [ath9k_htc]
Jun 28 17:39:23 localhost kernel: [<ffffffffa089405e>] htc_issue_send.constprop.1+0x5e/0x70 [ath9k_htc]
Jun 28 17:39:23 localhost kernel: [<ffffffffa0894435>] htc_send_epid+0x15/0x20 [ath9k_htc]
Jun 28 17:39:23 localhost kernel: [<ffffffffa089719c>] ath9k_wmi_cmd+0x11c/0x1d0 [ath9k_htc]
Jun 28 17:39:23 localhost kernel: [<ffffffffa089cf0e>] ath9k_regwrite+0x6e/0x130 [ath9k_htc]
Jun 28 17:39:23 localhost kernel: [<ffffffffa089d15b>] ath9k_reg_rmw+0x3b/0x50 [ath9k_htc]
Jun 28 17:39:23 localhost kernel: [<ffffffffa083281e>] ath9k_hw_ar9287_set_board_values+0x16e/0x360 [ath9k_hw]
Jun 28 17:39:23 localhost kernel: [<ffffffffa089ce20>] ? ath9k_regwrite_flush+0x30/0xb0 [ath9k_htc]
Jun 28 17:39:23 localhost kernel: [<ffffffffa081e824>] ath9k_hw_reset+0x3d4/0x1400 [ath9k_hw]
Jun 28 17:39:23 localhost kernel: [<ffffffffa089a87b>] ath9k_htc_start+0x9b/0x220 [ath9k_htc]
Jun 28 17:39:23 localhost kernel: [<ffffffffa052c5d1>] ieee80211_do_open+0x2c1/0xd60 [mac80211]
Jun 28 17:39:23 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff816fb80c>] ? notifier_call_chain+0x4c/0x70
Jun 28 17:39:23 localhost kernel: [<ffffffffa052d0c9>] ieee80211_open+0x59/0x60 [mac80211]
Jun 28 17:39:23 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff815e70ff>] __dev_open+0xcf/0x140
Jun 28 17:39:23 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff815e741d>] __dev_change_flags+0x9d/0x170
Jun 28 17:39:23 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff815e7519>] dev_change_flags+0x29/0x60
Jun 28 17:39:23 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff815f4797>] do_setlink+0x397/0xa50
Jun 28 17:39:23 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff8137d35c>] ? nla_put+0x2c/0x40
Jun 28 17:39:23 localhost kernel: [<ffffffffa0365bdf>] ? nl80211_send_wiphy+0x44f/0x2480 [cfg80211]
Jun 28 17:39:23 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff815f6d5c>] rtnl_newlink+0x50c/0x720
Jun 28 17:39:23 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff815f6943>] ? rtnl_newlink+0xf3/0x720
Jun 28 17:39:23 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff812f1400>] ? selinux_file_ioctl+0x50/0x100
Jun 28 17:39:23 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff812eb208>] ? security_capable+0x18/0x20
Jun 28 17:39:23 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff810931e9>] ? ns_capable+0x29/0x50
Jun 28 17:39:23 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff815f33b4>] rtnetlink_rcv_msg+0xa4/0x270
Jun 28 17:39:23 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff812ee100>] ? sock_has_perm+0x70/0x90
Jun 28 17:39:23 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff815d3502>] ? sock_queue_err_skb+0x72/0xe0
Jun 28 17:39:23 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff815f3310>] ? rtnetlink_rcv+0x30/0x30
Jun 28 17:39:23 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff81614ac9>] netlink_rcv_skb+0xa9/0xc0
Jun 28 17:39:23 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff815f3308>] rtnetlink_rcv+0x28/0x30
Jun 28 17:39:23 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff81614093>] netlink_unicast+0x103/0x210
Jun 28 17:39:23 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff816144d0>] netlink_sendmsg+0x330/0x770
Jun 28 17:39:23 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff81233002>] ? ep_poll_callback+0x2/0x160
Jun 28 17:39:23 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff815c9d4c>] sock_sendmsg+0x9c/0xe0
Jun 28 17:39:23 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff815c9a2e>] ? move_addr_to_kernel.part.18+0x1e/0x60
Jun 28 17:39:23 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff815ca1a3>] ___sys_sendmsg+0x3c3/0x3d0
Jun 28 17:39:23 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff81461500>] ? dev_attr_show+0x20/0x60
Jun 28 17:39:23 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff816f6392>] ? mutex_lock+0x12/0x2f
Jun 28 17:39:23 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff81206ef5>] ? __fget_light+0x25/0x70
Jun 28 17:39:23 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff815ca32e>] ? SYSC_sendto+0x17e/0x1c0
Jun 28 17:39:23 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff81206ef5>] ? __fget_light+0x25/0x70
Jun 28 17:39:23 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff815cb0a1>] __sys_sendmsg+0x51/0x90
Jun 28 17:39:23 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff815cb0f2>] SyS_sendmsg+0x12/0x20
Jun 28 17:39:23 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff817008e9>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
Jun 28 17:39:23 localhost kernel: ---[ end trace 77fdca8a3a2e9943 ]---
```

Some other details:

- I don't think it's because of a change in the driver since the issue occurs with all three kernels I have and I'm certain I'd have noticed it on the same day as any one of the kernel upgrades
- The issue occurred shortly after switching back to the open source radeon driver after switching to the proprietary fglrx drivers recently; don't know why that would be related but it's the only other kernel-related thing I've done recently

I reiterate that, aside from the error messages, my network connection is working perfectly. It must have been generating these for a few hours before I even noticed.

Answer (score 1):

Your USB wifi adapter requires a patch. The following commands work on Debian, it should not be all that different on Fedora. I assume you have linux headers and all that is necessary to compile source code.

```
  git clone https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes.git
  sudo dkms add ./rtl8192cu-fixes
  sudo dkms install 8192cu/1.7
  echo "blacklist rtl8192cu" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Comment: This is not an rtl8192cu adapter, it is an ath9k_htc adapter. I realize that some sources list that driver for this adapter but there are different versions with different chipsets. That's really neat though, I didn't know you could do that so easily.